# Does Openvino model optimiser have support for lambda layers

Tags: lambda, openvino

Converting a tensorflow model having lambda layers to IR format using openvino model optimiser throws error. Does openvino model optmizer have support for Lambda layers? Is there any way to convert Lambda layers using openvino model optimizer tool.

Tried converting using mo --saved_model_dir (.pb)

Answer (score 0):

According to the *TensorFlow 2 Keras Supported Operations* section in the documentation https://docs.openvino.ai/2023.0/openvino_resources_supported_operations_frontend.html, it lists the "*Lambda*" operation as supported by the OpenVINO Framework Frontend in 2023.0 release.

You can verify and retry your model conversion by using the Model Optimizer (MO) from the OpenVINO 2023.0 release. To make sure you are indeed using the correct MO, check the version in your environment:

```
$ mo --version 
Version of Model Optimizer is: 2023.0.0-10926-b4452d56304-releases/2023/0
```

If the issue persists with this version it may be due to an unknown bug. Recommend sharing your model files and relevant information on a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/issues) (i.e. topology type/architecture, TensorFlow version used, error logs from Model Optimizer, etc.).